# Setting conditional style on element dynamically created

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets, createelement

I'm listing a spreadsheet table on dynamic elements with javascript:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildLlamadas).getListLlamadas();

    function buildLlamadas(llamada){
      llamada.forEach(element => {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'cardLlamada';
        div.innerHTML = "<p id='fecha'>" +element[0]
                      +"</p><p id='persona'>"+element[1]
                      +"<span id='condicion' class='material-symbols-rounded'>"
                      +"fiber_manual_record</span>"
                      +"</p><p id='solicitud'>"+element[2]
                      +"</p><p id='respuesta'>"+element[5]
                      +"</p><ul id='menuLlamada'>"
                      +"<li>ARCHIVAR</li>"
                      +"<li id='editarLlamada'"
                      +"class='material-symbols-outlined'>"
                      +"<span>editar</span>edit_square</li>"
                      +"<li id='borrarLlamada'"
                      +"class='material-symbols-outlined'>"
                      +"<span>borrar</span>delete</li>"; 
        document.getElementById("dashBoard").appendChild(div);
        condicionPersona(element[3]);
      });
    }

    function condicionPersona(condicion){
      if(condicion == 'Cliente'){
        document.getElementById('persona').style.color = "#17B833";
      }else if(condicion == 'Prospecto'){
        document.getElementById('persona').style.color = "#742EF1";
        document.getElementById('condicion').style.visibility="visible";
      }
    }
  }, false);
```

I'm trying to use the function condicionPersona to change the color of the item person deppending of its condition, but doesn't work.
I'm working on google apps script.

Comment: What are you actually passing into `buildLlamadas() and `condicionPersona()`? Also, it looks like you are looping over `llamada`, but you are using the same ids for each element. IDs must be unique.

Comment: Please provide more information, a copy of the script will be helpful.

Comment: I already find the solution, I'm passing an array of data with llamada. I used a counter to index the element created, it also help me to get the record to modify or delete.
I also used children to change the persona attribute.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer? This will help another users of the community in your situation or on a similar one

Comment: Not right now, my answers are banned.